# Sharing folders between Windows 8 as host and Ubuntu 13.10 as guest in Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, 13.10

Sharing folders between Windows 8 as host and Ubuntu 13.10 as guest in Virtualbox 4.2.18 r88780 with adequate rights on the guest side. The shared folders in /media/sf_ appeared empty, with Nautilus returning an endless "Loading..." message (my own transaltion of French "Chargement..."). In the terminal, the ls command returns nothing and suspend the command prompt. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to DbhTPnx at this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181408
Remember, Virtualbox's "check for updates" doesn't indicate the availability of the 4.3 upgrade.

You should go to https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads download manually. And when update, You should reinstall the additions in the guest Ubuntu 13.10 and restart the guest.